# Object within Prototype

Tags: javascript

I have created an object within a prototype and I am trying to access a variable from the constructor with `this`, but the alert is returning `undefined`.

Constructor

```
function Example() {
    this.param1 = 'test';
}
```

Prototype

```
Example.prototype = {
    constructor: Example,
    obj: {
        sample:function() {

            alert(this.param1); // error undifined

        }
    }
};
```

Instantiate

```
var o = new Example();
o.obj.sample();
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: `this` is `.obj`.  Basically, you can't do that.

Comment: Aw dang it. That's what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this though

```
function Example() {
    this.param1 = 'test';
}
Example.prototype = {
    constructor: Example,
    obj: {
        sample:function(){
            alert(this.param1); // error undifined
        }
    }
};

var o = new Example();
o.obj.sample.call(o); // <--- I use "call" to supply the context. In this case, the context would be "o"
// or
o.obj.sample.bind(o)(); // or "bind" the context, in this case "o"
```

Comment: Makes having the method on the prototype pretty pointless though. At that point you might as well put it directly on `Example` and do `Example.sample(o)` or just not nest the method in the first place. And the `.bind()` just shouldn't be done. Doesn't make sense to create a new function just to invoke and discard it right away.

Comment: sure, I wasn't answering a theoretical question but rather - given his example, how to make it do what he wanted... alert "test". Your point is taken, of course.

Comment: This does work. So I will mark it the correct answer. However I am going to take a different approach to structuring my code. Thanks.

Comment: @Hubvill: This works too: [`Function.prototype.call.apply(Function.prototype.call, [Example.prototype.obj.sample, o])`](https://jsfiddle.net/8ojLj6pr/) ;-P Restructuring is the right decision.